# Enthought Canopy 1.1 giving error icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, enthought, icu, canopy

I have tried to get enthought canopy and follow the procedure. However, when I tried to run `./canopy`, it gave this error:

> Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)".

I cannot sudo because I am using the university's supercomputing account, no permission to do so. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You just need a copy of ICU installed on the system you are trying to run `canopy` on. You can do this by either installing it via the OS's package manager, or by getting a copy in your home directory, and telling `canopy` where to find it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

You can get precompiled copies of ICU from their download page (http://site.icu-project.org/download/51), and once installed you would do something like:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/path/to/icu/lib" ./canopy
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late response (we are monitoring the enthought tag, please use it for to get our attention more quickly).

These warning messages `Unable to load library icui18n` are spurious and shouldn't affect the usability of Canopy. We have turned these warnings off in version 1.2, which is coming out during the first week of January. Please post again if you see issues.