# Installing Enthought canopy on centos linux x86_64

Tags: linux, python-2.7, installation, enthought, canopy

Hi i am trying to run Canopy on Centos 6.4 x86_64 machine and the above method of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not working. I am very frustrated as i did as exactly said on

[icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374262/icui18n-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

but it is still complaining

```
 Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)" 



 Here is the command that i typed 

 $LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/usr/local/lib" ./canopy

 and /usr/local/bin contains

icu                   libicuio.so         libiculx.so.48        libicutu.so.48.1.1
libicudata.so         libicuio.so.48      libiculx.so.48.1.1    libicuuc.so
libicudata.so.48      libicuio.so.48.1.1  libicutest.so         libicuuc.so.48
libicudata.so.48.1.1  libicule.so         libicutest.so.48      libicuuc.so.48.1.1
libicui18n.so         libicule.so.48      libicutest.so.48.1.1  pkgconfig
libicui18n.so.48      libicule.so.48.1.1  libicutu.so
libicui18n.so.48.1.1  libiculx.so         libicutu.so.48
```

Please help and let me know if there are any questions.

I tried the same on my Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 machine and i get the same icui18n load library error but the Canopy RUNS !!!!

THanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icui18n error message is spurious (as you discovered on Ubuntu) and is suppressed in the forthcoming Canopy 1.2.

On your Centos install, are you using remote display, e.g. X?
If so, see:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/21873380-Canopy-Linux-version-fails-to-start-using-some-VNC-and-X-Windows-System-servers-Resolved-

Are there any other error messages on Centos?

Comment: Hi Jonathan,Hats off to you. That was exactly the problem. Seeing you responding on the weekend makes me thank you even more. Kindest regards

Comment: Thanks / my pleasure. Glad you are set!